# Django pass kwargs through URL

Tags: django, url, django-templates, django-views

The purpose of this section of code is to show all of the requests to join a group in a template similar to that shown below:

```
Request 1 | Add | Delete
Request 2 | Add | Delete
Request 3 | Add | Delete
....
```

What I have thought to do is to to make the 'add' and 'delete' button href's to a function in the view. However I am wondering what the proper way to pass a **kwarg from a template to a view. Else if there is any better way to accomplish this?

#### template

```
{% for asking in requested %}
    <a href={% url 'group_judge_request' group_profile.slug decision=0 %}>Cut {{ asking.user.username }}</a>
    <a href={% url 'group_judge_request' group_profile.slug decision=1 %}>Keep {{ asking.user.username }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

#### url

```
url(r'^judge_request/(?P<gslug>[\w-]+)$',
    group_judge_request,
    kwargs={'decision':'decision'},
    name='group_judge_request'),
```

#### view group_judge_restart

```
def group_judge_request(request, gslug, decision):
```

#### view group_requested_invites

```
def group_requested_invites(request, gslug):
  ....
  requested = GroupRequestToJoin.objects.filter(group=group_profile.group, checked=False)
  return render(request, "groups/group_requested_invites.html", {
    'requested' : requested,
    })
```

Error:

```
Don't mix *args and **kwargs in call to reverse()!
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the keyword syntax in the url templatetag? You would have something like this {% url 'group_judge_request' group_profile.slug 0 %}. Reading the Django docs, you can't mix positional and keyword syntax. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: Error: Reverse for 'group_judge_request' with arguments '('', 0)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['group/judge_request/(?P<gslug>[\\w-]+)$']

Comment: How about trying using the keyword syntax? {% url 'group_judge_request' gslug=group_profile.slug decision=0 %}.

Comment: Reverse for 'group_judge_request' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'decision': 0, u'gslug': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['group/judge_request/(?P<gslug>[\\w-]+)$']

Comment: I think it's because the gslug being passed is an empty string? It won't match the regex in your urlconf.

Comment: This thread got the answer here for passing two arguments in pk
http://stackoverflow.com/a/42431096/6786040

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to pass *kwargs like this from the template using the built-in url template tag.

There are two ways you can do this, one is to create two separate urls and pass the decision as a kwarg to the view:

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^judge_request_cut/(?P<gslug>[\w-]+)$',
    group_judge_request,
    kwargs={'decision': 0},
    name='group_judge_request_cut'),
url(r'^judge_request_keep/(?P<gslug>[\w-]+)$',
    group_judge_request,
    kwargs={'decision': 1},
    name='group_judge_request_keep'),
```

**template**

```
{% for asking in requested %}
    <a href={% url 'group_judge_request_cut' group_profile.slug decision=0 %}>Cut {{ asking.user.username }}</a>
    <a href={% url 'group_judge_request_keep' group_profile.slug decision=1 %}>Keep {{ asking.user.username }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Or you could pass the integer as a parameter:

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^judge_request/(?P<gslug>[\w-]+)/(?P<decision>\d{1})$',
    group_judge_request,
    name='group_judge_request'),
```

**template**

```
{% for asking in requested %}
    <a href={% url 'group_judge_request' group_profile.slug 0 %}>Cut {{ asking.user.username }}</a>
    <a href={% url 'group_judge_request' group_profile.slug 1 %}>Keep {{ asking.user.username }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to pass decision=[0|1] in the url if it is already defined in kwargs?

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to use a url query. So your url will be as follows:

```
<a href="{% url 'group_judge_request' group_profile.slug %}?decision=0">Cut {{asking.user.username }}</a>
```

You can then go on to list the queries using:

```
request.META['QUERY_STRING']
```

Comment: I personally prefer request.GET['decision'] or request.GET.get('decision', False) if you want an unquery-stringed default version. But it depends also on the use case.