# How to pass more than one variables to modelViewSet in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am using http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

I have the scenario where I want to pass two or more variables based on that I need to fetch data from database. In the following code only pk is there which I want to replace with two other fields in database.

Also please suggest how can I write my urlconfig the same.

Views.py

```
class ExampleViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    model = myTable
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = myTable.objects.all()
        serializer = mySerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = myTable.objects.all()
        s = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = mySerializer(s)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Serializer.py

```
class Serializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = myTable
        fields = ('attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3')
```

Comment: How does the Serializer look like? Can you give an example where the fields are missing? Do you mean for a ForeignKey?

Comment: @DenisCornehl edited question with serializer example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of how you might implement what you want:

```
class ExampleViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
# This code saves you from repeating yourself
queryset = myTable.objects.all()
serializer_class = mySerializer

def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Get your variables from request
    var1 = request.QUERY_DICT.get('var1_name', None) # for GET requests
    var2 = request.DATA.get('var2_name', None) # for POST requests
    if var1 is not None:
        # Get your data according to the variable var1
        data = self.get_queryset().filter(var1)
        serialized_data = self.get_serializer(data, many=True)
        return Response(serialized_data.data)

    if var2 is not None:
        # Do as you need for var2
        return Response(...)

    # Default behaviour : call parent
    return super(ExampleViewSet, self).list(request, *args, **kwargs)

def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Same for retrieve
    # 1. get your variable xyz from the request
    # 2. Get your object based on your variable's value
    s = myTable.objects.get(varX=xyz)
    # 3. Serialize it and send it as a response
    serialized_data = self.get_serializer(s)
    return Response(serialized_data.data)
    # 4. Don't forget to treat the case when your variable is None (call parent method)
```

As for the ***urlconf***, it depends on how you want to send your variables (get, post or through the url).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried your answer. I am getting an exception AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'QUERY_DICT' related to GET request

Comment: Oups, my bad. It is QUERY_PARAMS, see [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests#query_params). I have't tested this exact code, but this is how I usually do it, so I hope it works now.

Answer (score 14):

Here is how you would do it with the recent Django REST Framework.

Assuming your variables are in the resource URLs like so:

```
GET /parent/:id/child/
GET /parent/:id/child/:id/
```

Then:

urls.py:

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'parent/(?P<parent_id>.+)/child', views.ExampleViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

views.py:

```
class ExampleViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = Serializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        parent = self.kwargs['parent']
        return myTable.objects.filter(parent=parent)
```

Where the 'parent' in the queryset part is your parent object. You may need to adjust it a little, of course, but the idea is encapsulated in the kwargs.

This solution will also save you a little code and you can make it into a full blown `ModelViewSet` just by subclassing it.

Hope that helps.

More here: [DRF Filtering against the URL](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-the-url).

Answer (score -1):

urls.py

```
  url( 
        regex=r'^teach/(?P<pk>\d+?)/(?P<pk1>\d+?)/$', 
        view=teach_update.as_view(), 
        name='teach' 
   )
```

Templates

```
<td><a href="/teach/{{tid}}/{{i.id}}"><button type="button" class="btn       
btn-warning">Update</button></a></td>
```

Views.py

```
class teach_update(view):
     def get(self,request,**kwargs):
        dist=self.kwargs['pk']
        ddd=self.kwargs['pk1']
```